# Accord masculin/féminin après "la totalité de...", "l'intégralité de..."

Tags: accord

J'ai un doute permanent et je ne parviens pas à retrouver la règle concernée.

Par exemple doit-on écrire :
"L'intégralité du produit était développé"
ou
"L'intégralité du produit était développé**e**" ?

Comment: Pour s'accorder, il faut le verbe: se développer. Sinon il n'y a pas d'accord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Après la totalité de, le verbe se met au singulier ou au pluriel
> suivant le sens. Au singulier, si l'on veut insister sur l'idée
> d'ensemble, de globalité, ou si celle-ci prédomine : la totalité des
> vivres sera acheminée par avion. Au pluriel, si l'on veut insister sur
> l'idée de nombre ou si celle-ci prédomine : la totalité des gens ont
> voté.

Source : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/totalit%C3%A9/78604#difficulte

Voir aussi : https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/accord-du-verbe-avec-un-sujet-collectif

Pour aller plus loin : http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/accord-avec-un-sujet-singulier-ayant-un-sens-pluriel-a5352133